# Exception never reaching the handler in async method (C#)

Tags: c#, asynchronous, exception

I have a simplistic structure and I have a hard time understanding why it works (or does not work) how I think it should work.

Basically, there are two methods

```
private async void DoStuff()
{
    try {
        AuthenticationStuff();
    }catch(UnauthorizedAccessException){
        UI.Display("AMAGAD!");
    }
}

private async void AuthenticationStuff()
{
    var user = GetUser();
    if(user == null) throw new UnauthorizedAccessException();

    DoMoreAuthenticationStuff();
}
```

Now the problem is that the exception never reaches `DoStuff()` method's handler. My first instinct was that "hey, it's an async method, I have to await it", but I can't do that either as apparently async void is different from async `Task<void>`.

I am trying to understand what's going on in here. Why isn't the exception going to the handler, but instead the debugger breaks at `"DoMoreAuthenticationStuff()`" with an unhandeled exception error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions raised by an `async void` method go directly to the `SynchronizationContext` that was active at the time the method started. This is one of the reasons why you should avoid `async void`. I cover this and other reasons in my MSDN article [Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

To catch exceptions like this, change your `async void` method to `async Task` and `await` the returned task.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen! That's exactly what I was looking for. And that article of yours was very insightful!

Answer (score 0):

> My first instinct was that "hey, it's an async method, I have to await
>   it", but I can't do that either as apparently async void is different
>   from async Task.

You can just say `async Task MyMethod()`. Then you can await its result to propagate the exception (and to wait for completion).

Also observe Stephen Cleary's answer for more details.